# R Converting reshaped data into excel

Tags: r, excel

I'd like to convert the following into a seperate spreadsheet:

```
install.packages('reshape2')
library(reshape2)
data <- read.csv("test.csv", header=FALSE)
dcast(data, V1 ~ V2, value.var="V3")
```

So after I have reshaped the data in the csv file, I'd like to put it in a separate excel spreadsheet. How do I go about this?

Comment: See for example the `openxlsx` or `WriteXLS` packages.

Comment: or `write.table(df, "test.csv", sep = "\t", row.names = F, quote = F)` but you have to save the results of the dcast to the object ex. `df`